# Which site use an add-in

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-addin, sharepoint-on-prem

I've developed a SharePoint add-in. It is available through the app catalog.
What would be the best way to know all the SharePoint webs using (added in site content) this add-in within a SharePoint WebApplication ? (I cannot use server code)
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To 'Big Brother' track every usage of an Add-In (or anything you want to track)

- add a global List everyone can only **Add** content to
  A Survey would be great because OOTB one can only see their own entries
- change your Add-In to write an Item to this List, setting the Title to the site name : `_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl`
- Change the AllItems View so it shows 0 items (user won't see anything)
  Add **Personal** Views to show whatever you as admin want to see
  If you GroupBy Title you have the site names

Comment: That's clever thanks ! But what about an add-in already installed ?

Comment: I don't think Microsoft programmed that.. the AddIn model is kinda like an IKEA Billy cabinet, you buy it once then can do whatever you want with it.. To SharePoint it is just a webpart being used on a page. There is no info about "where are all Content Editor WebParts used?" either. So you have to deep dive and check every page for AddIns if you need that info.